# handling splice with associative arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array called as wcs declared using  `var wcs= new Array();`.

I do add items like this, `wcs[indx] = value`. where i will keep on changing the indx value, so at times, my array will be looking like this
`wcs[2] ='a'; wcs[5]=')';`

when i call the splice method on this array, all the created indices are re-indexed, meaning they become reset from 0...

how to avoid this in javascript & jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your own splice method that works the way you want. If you specify the input, processing and expected output, you might get some help with that.

If you simply want a copy of the array, you may be after the *concat* method.

Comment: I have resorted to using objects in arrays that can be a lot better than associative arrays.

Comment: That is one of the beauties of javascript - you can emulate patterns and features of other languages, but only to the extent that you need them. Attempting to fully emulate associative arrays would be a mistake, but emulating certain features make sense.